# Why isn't PHP/MySQL COUNT within Formidable Pro working?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, formidable

I want to get the number of entries in the database to establish if the current user already has an entry. The result should be a number which I can use elsewhere.
The following code doesn't seem to work. Can some one help me out?

```
...

add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'een_maal', 10, 3);
function een_maal($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
if(!is_admin()){
global $wpdb, $user_ID;
//  $entry_id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;

$paginatitel = do_shortcode("[page_slug]");

$entries = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ". 
$wpdb->prefix ."frm_item_metas em LEFT JOIN ". 
$wpdb->prefix ."frm_items e ON (em.item_id = e.id) 
WHERE 
form_id=23 AND
em.field_id= 591 AND 
em.meta_value=$paginatitel AND 
user_id = $user_ID
"));

if(count($entries) <= 0) //limit to one entry per option.
$errors = 'You have already selected that option';
}
return count($entries);
echo count($entries);
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'een_maal' );

...
```

Result seems to be always "0".

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return a column, but you are not specifying the column name, as per [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/).

However, I think what you would rather want to do is count the number of rows returned, perhaps?  Take a quick look at all the options available to you at the [Wordpress Developer reference site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/).

Maybe something like this will work?

```
$entries = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM ". 
$wpdb->prefix ."frm_item_metas em LEFT JOIN ". 
$wpdb->prefix ."frm_items e ON (em.item_id = e.id) 
WHERE 
form_id=23 AND
em.field_id= 591 AND 
em.meta_value=$paginatitel AND 
user_id = $user_ID
"));
```

I changed get_col to get_var and tried count(*) to return the number of returned rows.

Answer (score -2):

James, thanks for your input. i got it working:

```
function een_maal($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
    global $wpdb, $user_ID;
    $paginatitel = do_shortcode("[page_slug]");
$UID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$count_query = $wpdb->prepare("select count(*) from YYC_frm_item_metas em LEFT JOIN YYC_frm_items e ON (em.item_id = e.id)
    WHERE 
        form_id = 23 AND
        user_id = '$user_ID' AND
        em.field_id = 591 AND 
        em.meta_value = '$paginatitel'
");
         $num = $wpdb->get_var($count_query);
         return $num;
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'een_maal' );
```

Comment: You can thank James by marking their answer as accepted. There's no need to repost their work as another answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers